# How to make a boot profile permanent?

Tags: linux, boot, livecd

I have a Finnix live CD. I can customize it by [remastering](http://www.finnix.org/Remastering_Finnix) it. When I boot with the live CD I need to make a little change in the boot profile

The boot profile before making the changes is

> linux apm=power-off vga=791 initrd=minirt quiet

The boot profile after making the change become

> linux apm=power-off vga=791 initrd=minirt quiet root=/dev/sr0

Now, I need to make this change (**adding root=/dev/sr0**) permanent. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find **isolinux.cfg** in your CD file system (mounted at /mnt/hda1 in your remastering guide).
In this file there is a line like

```
APPEND apm=power-off vga=791 initrd=minirt quiet
```

edit it like you want before launching stage1 and stage2 scripts.